# How to get rid of Apple Mach-O Linker Errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

First I had a `Could not build module Foundation`

Tried to solve that by setting `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to `NO`

After another build I get these strange errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKBaseEffect", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_EZAudioPlotGLKViewController in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JSONModel+CoreData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSManagedObject_$_JSONModel in JSONModel+CoreData.o
      objc-class-ref in JSONModel+CoreData.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZAudioPlotGLKViewController in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_SSLClose", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket closeWithError:] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLCopyPeerTrust", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_continueSSLHandshake] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLCreateContext", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLGetBufferedReadSize", referenced from:
      ___33-[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers]_block_invoke in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLHandshake", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_continueSSLHandshake] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLRead", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetCertificate", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetConnection", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetEnabledCiphers", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetIOFuncs", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetPeerDomainName", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetPeerID", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMax", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMin", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetSessionOption", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLWrite", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doWriteData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_glBindBuffer", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateBufferPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateRollingPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glBufferData", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateBufferPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateRollingPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glBufferSubData", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _clearRollingPlot] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateBufferPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateRollingPlotBufferWithAudioReceived:withBufferSize:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _updateRollingPlotDisplay] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController glkView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _refreshWithBackgroundColor:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glDrawArrays", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glEnableVertexAttribArray", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glGenBuffers", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController viewDidLoad] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController viewDidLoad] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glPopMatrix", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glPushMatrix", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
  "_glVertexAttribPointer", referenced from:
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawBufferPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
      -[EZAudioPlotGLKViewController _drawRollingPlotWithView:drawInRect:] in EZAudioPlotGLKViewController-11ED1EEF7D7801BD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am clueless. This happened after I updated this project from our SVN repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link in the following frameworks:

```
CoreData.framework
GLKit.framework
Security.framework
```

Which is accomplished in the following bit of Xcode:

[image]

Comment: @WarrenBurton Missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works now. Also, in an audio framework I'm using there was some extra functionality with some kind of audio plotting that was using OPENGL and a couple of other extra frameworks, which I commented out now, as I'm not using them at all.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! You saved me several hours.